# PHP Output MS SQL to a downloadable CSV or Excel file

Tags: php, sql-server, csv, download

I'm trying to output data returned by an MS SQL query to an Excel or CSV file with PHP.
I've used the script in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499644/php-export-to-csv-from-sql-server) and can output the file OK. Without the header lines (at the bottom of my code) it saves in my server's folder structure rather than outputs as a download to the browser.

If I add the header lines, it ouputs to a CSV file but writes the page's HTML to the file rather than the extract from the database! Am I missing a setting somewhere? I tried running the code on a page with no HTML in it (PHP and SQL code only), but it still happens.

```
        // Give the file a suitable name:
            $FileName= $PartNumber.".csv";
            $fp = fopen($FileName, 'w');
        // Connect to MS SQL server; the actual database is chosen in the form
        // ConnSQL defined in inc/dbconn/config.php
            ConnSQL($idDatabase);

        // the query is a biggie; here it is:
            require 'inc_sql.php';

        // run it through the SQL server
            $rstBOM = sqlsrv_query($GLOBALS['ConnSQL'], $sqlBOM);

        while ($export= sqlsrv_fetch_array($rstBOM, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            if (!isset($headings))
                {
                    $headings = array_keys($export);
                    fputcsv($fp, $headings, ',', '"');
                }
                fputcsv($fp, $export, ',', '"');
            }

        // force download csv - exports HTML to CSV!
            header("Content-type: application/force-download"); 
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$FileName.'"'); 
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
            header("Content-length: ". filesize($FileName)); 
            header('Content-Type: application/excel'); 
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$FileName.'"');

            fclose($fp);
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to output your csv file to the browser simply by putting

```
readfile($FileName);
```

At the end of your code after the `fclose($fp);` function.

Otherwise, browser receives the headers for files, but no content in sent from your PHP code.

You could also generate your csv file on the fly and just `echo $csvFileContents;` instead. This would prevent server from creating and writing data to file, which could lead to security breaches.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, but that's still just outputting the page html to the csv file. If I take the header files out of the script with that line in place, the CSV info (from the query) is written to the html page.